# QTableView disconnect all delegates

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have a QTableView and selfmade delegate to show images inside its cells.
To connect the delegate to some column I use this:

```
ui->tableViewQueryResult->setItemDelegateForColumn(ui->lineEditPicColumn->text().toInt() - 1, new ImageDelegate());
```

Is it possible to disconnect **all** of the delegates connected previously? I've tried

```
ui->tableViewQueryResult->setItemDelegate(NULL);
```

but that crashes the program at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Qt docs for `setItemDelegate()`:

> Any existing delegate will be removed, but not deleted.
>   QAbstractItemView does not take ownership of delegate.

What you need to do is for each column delegate that you are customizing, remember (somewhere) the old delegate first and eventually restory it. You also need to delete unused delegates. The *View will not do it for you, cause it does not take ownership of the delegate.

You also need to use `setColumnDelegate()` consequently. If you set delegate for column, you have to restore it for column, not for all items.

Here's how you do it:

```
class Aaaa
{
    QHash<int,QAbstractItemDelegate*> delegateForColumn; // <- keep this in class members;
}
```

Then:

```
void Aaaa::setMyDelegate()
{
    // Getting column to set on
    int column = ui->lineEditPicColumn->text().toInt() - 1;

    // Remembering old delegate
    delegateForColumn[column] = ui->tableViewQueryResult->columnDelegate(column);

    // Setting new delegate
    ui->tableViewQueryResult->setColumnDelegate(column, new ImageDelegate());
}

void Aaaa::unsetMyDelegate()
{
    // Getting column to reset delegate for
    int column = ui->lineEditPicColumn->text().toInt() - 1;

    // Getting current delegate for column, keeping it in local variable, cause we will need to delete it later on
    QAbstractItemDelegate* old = ui->tableViewQueryResult->columnDelegate(column);

    // Setting new delegate (the initial one) to the column
    ui->tableViewQueryResult->setColumnDelegate(column, delegateForColumn[column]);

    // Deleting our custom delegate, cause we don't need it anymore
    delete old;

    // Removing custom delegate from our registry - a cleanup
    delegateForColumn.remove(column);
}
```